# IIS7 Integrated Pipeline - Response.End not ending the request

Tags: iis-7, integrated-pipeline-mode

I have the following bit of code that worked as expected before we upgraded to Integrated Pipeline in IIS7.

```
public void RedirectPermanently(string url, bool clearCookies)
{
  Response.ClearContent();
  Response.StatusCode = 301;
  Response.AppendHeader("Location", url);
  if(clearCookies)
  {
    Response.Cookies.Clear();
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
  }
}
```

Previously when this method was executed, if clearCookies was true, the response would be sent to the client and request processing would end.  Now under Integrated Pipeline Response.End() does not seem to end processing.  The page continues running as if the method was never called.

Big question is, why and what changed!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Response.End` will only raise `ThreadAbortException` when `HttpContext.IsInCancellablePeriod` is true.

One side effect of `Response.Flush()` is that is causes `HttpContext.IsInCancellablePeriod` to become false when executing in integrated pipeline mode.

Try removing `Response.Flush()` from your code.  Ending the response will cause the response stream to be flushed anyway.